# Why is .toUpperCase() not working?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, framerjs

I am very new with framer.js and 
I am just following a book called http://coffeescript-for-framerjs.com/#buy where it's written 
[image]

`fruits[1].toUpperCase()` It was working properly

```
fruits.toUpperCase()
```

Here in book it's **fruit** not **fruits** i tried both but getting error

Now i got it that **toUpperCase()** is a string method so it will not work with Array. but what exactly book is saying here then.

Comment: An array doesn't have the method .toUpperCase.

Comment: As `fruits` is an array and it doesn't have the method. `toUpperCase()` is string method. So error is correct, Use a simple for loop

Answer (score 8):

Why:

`.toUpperCase()` is a method of the `String.prototype`, not the `Array.prototype`.

An example of the correct syntax in your case:

```
var fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi']

for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    fruits[i] = fruits[i].toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fruits is an array. toUpperCase function is not defined on array but for string objects.

Answer (score 1):

Because `fruits[1]` referring to your `array` element which is of type `String`

`toUpperCase()` can only be used for `String` type.

`fruits.toUpperCase()` is failing fruits is of type `Array`

[Read More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it work that way:

```
Array.prototype.toUpperCase = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        if(typeof this[i] === 'string')
            this[i] = this[i].toUpperCase();
}
```

To test:

```
var fruits = ["oranges", "apples", "bananas"];
fruits.toUpperCase();
console.log(fruits.toString());
```

> ORANGES,APPLES,BANANAS

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to solve it with the below:

```js
let fruit = new Array("peach","orange", "mango", "apple" );
console.log(fruit.toString().toUpperCase());
```

Comment: @MakwanaPrahlad sure!

So the other answers called the array to a string in one line and then called the string to all Uppercase in the next line. 

I opted to join them together in one line to show I was calling this array to a string to make it uppercase. 

I am new to coding so I don't know if condensing it this way is best practice, but it did work for me and saved an extra step